# Android spinner setAdapter hides progressbar

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, android-spinner, android-adapter

I don't know why but when i call setAdapter method for my adapter the rest of the view disappears. I'm going to explain what I mean. That's my view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/day_filter"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:textSize="17sp"
              android:text="Text"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:background="@color/btnBgColor"
              android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

          <RelativeLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:background="@color/btnBgColor">
             <Spinner
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                 android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
                 android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                 android:id="@+id/filterSpinner"
                 />
          </RelativeLayout>
       </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/myList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>

   <View
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="1dp"
       android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
       />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_loading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

What I what is simple, show the ProgressBar and hide the RecyclerView while data are loading. The strange thing is that it works well if I don't call the `setAdapter` method.
I have this method to do what I need

```
@Override
    public void showHideIfLoading(boolean loading) {
        myList.setVisibility(loading ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);
        myProgress.setVisibility(loading ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

I call this method before loading data in this way

```
    showHideIfLoading(true)
    viewModel.getList().observe(this, new Observer<List<User>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<User> user) {
                    if (users != null) {
                        dataLoaded(users);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Inside `dataLoaded()` I call `showHideIfLoading(false)` of course
Everything works fine but I've got a spinner and I need to fill it and set the adapter. So, That's what I wrote so far

```
filterValues.add(getResources().getString(R.string.all_category));
        filterValues.add(getResources().getString(R.string.accounting));
        filterValues.add(getResources().getString(R.string.part_time));
        filterValues.add(getResources().getString(R.string.hr));
        filterValues.add(getResources().getString(R.string.full_time));
        filterAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, filterValues) {........
```

and then

```
filterSpinner.setAdapter(filterAdapter);
```

If i comment this line I can see the ProgressBar. If I keep the line I can't see the Progress. Te view has a white background and just fill the list when data are loaded. How can I see the ProgressBar and set the adapter of my spinner without this issue?